# Cookie Alert on Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, android-versions, cookies

Is there a way to block eu cookie alert on android?

Tried Adblock browser - no luck. and i am using a cookie alert blocker on PC, which doesn't work on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this? If this is what you are looking for it can be done inside the chrome browser on Android. It's almost at the bottom.

https://www.howtogeek.com/241006/how-to-block-third-party-cookies-in-every-web-browser/